# Communicating with Language

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Can you please help me with this problem?

There are $n$ people living on a planet. It is known that their planet has $6$ languages and each person knows every language. It is also known that any two people communicate with exactly one of the six languages. What is the minimum value of $n$ such that there always exists a trio which mutually communicates with each other in the same language?

Comment: What are your ideas on it?

Comment: I have no idea about it

Comment: It looks like we want to know the smallest $n$ such that given any 6-coloring of the edges of the complete graph $K_n$ there will be a $K_3$ whose edges are of the same color.  This is a generalization of the problems in Ramsey theory on 2-coloring.

Answer (score 2):

Let's consider the complete graph with $n$ vertices, $C_{n}$ (think of every vertex as a person). Represent each language by a color, and color each edge of the graph with the color corresponding to the language spoken by the two people at the vertices.

So, for example, if Alice and Bob spoke to each other in English, and English was assigned the color red, then the edge between the vertices corresponding to Alice and Bob would be colored red.

Now, we are asking if we can guarantee a monochromatic triangle (or $C_{3}$) in the complete graph of $n$ vertices, colored with $6$ colors. The minimal $n$ for which this is possible can be seen to be a certain [generalized](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RamseyNumber.html) or [multicolor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey%27s_theorem) Ramsey number.

This seems to be an [unsolved](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey%27s_theorem#A_multicolour_example%3a_R.283.2C3.2C3.29_.3D_17) problem, which is highly unusual for a homework question (unless you are [George Dantzig](http://www.umass.edu/wsp/statistics/tales/dantzig.html)).

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I think you are right about the exact Ramsey number $R(3,3,3,3,3,3)$ being unknown.  Perhaps the problem has gotten garbled somewhere in being retold.

Comment: On page 2 of [these lecture notes](http://math.mit.edu/~fox/18315/18315notes3.pdf) there are bounds on $R(3,3,3,3,3,3)$ as being at least $5^3=125$ but not more than $7!=5040$.